# ¿Cómo insertar en una consulta con codeigniter una contraseña con AES_Encrypt?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Estoy tratando de desarrollar un modulo para actualizar la contraseña de usuarios. Sin embargo cuando ejecuto

```
$this->db->update('usuarios', array('DataPass'=>'AES_ENCRYPT($password,\'mykey\')'));
```

Esto me genera la siguiente consulta:

```
UPDATE `usuarios` SET `DataPass` = 'AES_ENCRYPT($password,\'mykey\')'WHERE `id` = '1'
```

El problema es que el argumento se guarda en el campo Datapass como cadena de texto:

> DataPass'=>'AES_ENCRYPT($password,'mykey')

Si ejecuto la consulta directa en el manejador de db sin las comillas funciona bien.
Alguna idea, soy nuevo con el query builder de codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con el método `update()` no es posible enlazar valores que ejecuten funciones del motor de base de datos, porque, según [el manual](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html), los datos son escapados para producir consultas seguras.

Probablemente tengas que usar otra vía para realizar la actualización, por ejemplo:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `usuarios` SET `DataPass` = AES_ENCRYPT(?, 'mykey') WHERE `id` = ?";
$this->db->query($sql, [$password, $this->id]);
```

**Nota:** La función `AES_ENCRYPT` no se encierra entre comillas, solo los parámetros que se incluyan directamente como cadena, en este caso, solo `'mykey'`.

Referencia: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html

Comment: Tienes razón, de esta manera funciona perfecto.